# How many ways of creating a password of length 7

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways of creating a password of length $7$ given constraint:
$5$ upper case, $1$ lower case, and $1$ digit.

My answer is there are $^7C_{5}$ way of choosing position for uppercase letter, and for each one of the $^7C_{5}$ way we have $26^5$ ways of choosing a password as we have $26$ alphabets.

For each of $^7C_{5}$ x $26^5$ ways of choosing above, we can pick $^2C_{1}$ position in the password string to place a lowercase, and for each one of the $^2C_{1}$ ways we have $26$ way of choosing lowercase.

For each of $^7C_5$ x $26^5$ x $^2C_1$ x $26$ ways of choosing upper case and lower cases, we have $10$ options to pick digit for the very last position left over.

Then my answer is : $^7C_5$ x $26^5$ x $^2C_1$ x $26$ x $10$ passwords can be created.

Please tell me how I got it wrong?

Comment: Seems right, except that in your final answer I think you mean $26$ is place of $6$, and you could note that 1c2 is $2$. Try using proper editing for the math in your question, as explained [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

There are $7$ ways to choose the position of the lower case letter and $26$ ways to fill that position with a lower case letter.  There are $6$ positions remaining.  Choose one of them to fill with a digit.  That digit may be chosen in $10$ ways.  The remaining five positions must be filled with upper case letters.  Each of those positions may be filled in $26$ ways.  Hence, there are 
$$7 \cdot 26 \cdot 6 \cdot 10 \cdot 26^5 = 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 10 \cdot 26^6$$
admissible passwords, as you found.

Comment: No, the answer does not depend on whether we start with the lower case letter, the digit, or the upper case digits.  If I had started with the digit, I would have $7$ ways of choosing the position for the digit, $10$ ways of choosing the digit, $6$ ways of choosing the position for the lower case letter, $26$ ways of choosing the lower case letter, and $26$ ways of filling each of the remaining five positions with upper case letters, which again yields $$7 \cdot 10 \cdot 6 \cdot 26 \cdot 26^5 = 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 10 \cdot 26^6$$

Comment: So, As the positions are basically slots and nothing else, their order does not matter. That makes the original post correct

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Thanks, I learnt something useful today!

Comment: Thanks both of you @Taussig and @Soumalya!

Answer (score 0):

We should choose the element which wee include in the password

Eg:***a letter from the alphabet*** or  ***a digit form 0-9***;

Then we consider the permutations including those elements.

***Problem:***

Choosing a lowercase letter = $26\choose 1$ = $26$

Choosing a digit = $10\choose1$ = $10$

Problem occurs when choosing the uppercase letters.

Consider the number of total combinations in a case-wise manner

Case 1: All distinct letters : ${26 \choose 5} * 26 * 10$

Case 2: $2$ identical letters and $3$ distinct letters= $ {26 \choose 1} * {25 \choose 3} * 26 * 10$

Case 3: $3$ identical letters and $2$ distinct letters= ${26 \choose 1} * {25\choose 2} * 26 * 10$

Case 4: $4$ identical letters and $1$ distinct letters= ${26 \choose 1} * {25 \choose 1} * 26 * 10$

Case 5: All identical letters= ${26 \choose 1} *26 * 10$

Let us denote $P_i$ to the number of permutations for the $i^{th}$ case.
Thereby;
$$P_1 = {26 \choose 5} * 7!* 26 * 10$$ 
$$P_2 = {26 \choose 1} * {25 \choose 3} * 26 * 10* \frac{7!}{2!}$$
$$P_3 = {26 \choose 1} * {25\choose 2} * 26 * 10* \frac{7!}{3!} $$
$$P_4 = {26 \choose 1} * {25 \choose 1} * 26 * 10* \frac{7!}{4!} $$
$$P_5 = {26 \choose 1} * 26 * 10* \frac{7!}{5!}$$

Therefore $$\sum_{i=1}^5 P_i $$ would give the total number of passwords possible.

Comment: Be careful.  Note that \begin{align*} 5 & = 5\\ & = 4 + 1\\ & = 3 + 2\\ & = 3 + 1 + 1\\ & = 2 + 2 + 1\\ & = 2 + 1 + 1 + 1\\ & = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1\end{align*}  That said, division into cases is not necessary.